# How to remove all the elements with null id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to check for ANY element on the page where the id has no value, and then remove them using jQuery's `remove()`.

This is how the id's look when they have no value passed from the CMS:

```
<iframe id class="iframeCol"...></iframe>
<div id class="sectional">..</div>
```

How do I target any and all elements where the id is as above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the attribute selector to achieve this:

```js
$('[id=""]').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<iframe id class="iframeCol">Remove this</iframe>
<div id class="sectional">And remove this</div>

<div>Keep this</div>
<div id="foo">And this</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect. If I wanted to apply this to a selector such as `$('#').click(...` would it be like this:

`$('[]').remove();`?

Comment: @RebeccaO'Sullivan what's wrong with attribute selector `'[id=""]'`???  The only downside i can think of is it will match `id=""` not only `id` but i don't see how it could be an issue because anyway i'm not sure just `id` is valid regarding spec, `id` isn't a boolean attribute

Comment: @A.Wolff when I used the above it worked perfectly for removing the iframe and div, but I want to remove a click function that's associated with the div id too. So I have this: `$('#').click(function() {...});` whenever the div id doesn't exist. I would like to remove this line of code too, to cut out unnecessary extra code.

Comment: If you remove the div then any event handlers on it will also be removed. Also note that you can't select an element by an attribute it doesn't have, hence `$('#')` won't work, you'd need to use another means to select the element. By class for example

Comment: @RebeccaO'Sullivan, that's a dangerous road, you're taking. Because by default everything has an empty id *(unless you've define one)*; and you don't know yet what this "everything" may include in the future. You should better use some including definition instead of an excluding. A set of ID's, classNames data- or other attributes, ... this list can be extended at any time if necessary. Or at least norrow down the set you address, like `.foo[id=""]`.

Answer (score 2):

Can do it without jQuery, too:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('[id=""]'), function(node) {
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
});
```

I know you specified the use of jQuery, but it's here just for reference.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('body *').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('id'))
  if ($(this).attr('id') == '') {
    $(this).remove();

  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe id class="iframeCol" ...></iframe>
<div id class="sectional">..</div>
<div class="sectional">123</div>
<div id='asd' class="sectional">asd</div>
```

Compare ID if equals blank remove

Answer (score 1):

If you like vanilla JavaScript with no jQuery you can use this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[id=""]').forEach(function(item){
    item.parentNode.removeChild(item);
});
```

```html
<iframe id class="iframeCol">Remove this</iframe>
<div id class="sectional">And remove this</div>

<div>Keep this</div>
<div id="foo">And this</div>
```

Brief explanation:

[Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
Select a list of elements using a [CSS3 selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/).

[Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
Loop in your selection.

HTML DOM parentNode Property
Get the node of the parent node.

[Node.removeChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild)
Removes a child node from the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Alternate way
$('body').find('*[id=""]').remove();
```

```js
var removedItems = 
     $('iframe, div')
     .map(
      function(){ if($(this).attr('id') == "") return this}
     )
    .remove()
    .toArray();
console.log("See the removed items");
console.log(removedItems);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<iframe id class="iframeCol">Remove this</iframe>
<div id class="sectional">And remove this</div>

<div>Keep this</div>
<div id="foo">And this</div>

<div id="">Remove this</div>
```

@Rory McCrossan : Thanks for the snippet.

Comment: `map()` seems pretty redundant here

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : I just wanted to show him alternate ways, if He want to use

Comment: That's fine, but `map()` is used to create an array

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for your feedback, I've updated my answer.